# identify paragraph and or page boundaries of extracted text from pdf documents using c#

Tags: c#

I am developing application and I need to identify paragraph from pdf.
I need to extract the text and identify paragraph.
*Is there any way to extract text and identify paragraph and or page boundaries of extracted text from pdf documents using c#?*

Comment: add the code which you have tried so far....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFs are a binary format, try using one of these to read it in:
http://www.pdflib.com/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Once you have the stream in, you should be able to check for
 line breaks/returns (\n/\r) or tabs \t to find new paragraphs.